# Detect mouse being held down

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, event-handling

I am trying to be able to detect when a mouse is held down instead of clicked.  This is what I have, but instead of a click count I want to be able to detect the mouse being held down.

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event;
{
    //instead of clickCount I want my if statement to be 
    // if the mouse is being held down.
    if ([event clickCount] < 1) 
    {

    }
    else if ([event clickCount] > 1)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this event not fire when the user clicks-and-holds?

Comment: At the time of the `mouseDown` event, the computer can't see far enough in the future to tell if the user is *going* to keep holding the mouse button down or not. Usually, to implement drag-and-drop, you only figure out what is being dragged on the `mouseDown` event, you watch the `mouseUp` event like Kristian outlines and also figure out where the item was dropped, and handle the `mouseMoved` (or whatever it's called) event (which checks `mouseIsHeldDown`) to see if something is being dragged.

Comment: Another option is to set some kind of delayed callback in the `mouseDown`. If the mouse is released, you clear the callback, and if the callback fires, then the mouse button has been held down at least that amount of time. This similar to how key repeat works.

Comment: @Mike: -1 answer posted as comment :)

Comment: @Iulius: Posted as comment since I don't feel it was complete enough to be an answer. Also, I'm not familiar enough with Obj-C.

Comment: @Mike: I just thought it was funny that your comments covered both the possibilities from the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably you want to detect whether the mouse is being held down for a certain period of time. This is pretty straightforward; it just requires a timer.

In your `mouseDown:`, you start a timer which will fire after your chosen period. You need to stick this into an ivar, because you will also refer to it in `mouseUp:`

```
- (void)mouseDown: (NSEvent *)theEvent {
    mouseTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:mouseHeldDelay
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(mouseWasHeld:)
                                                userInfo:theEvent
                                                 repeats:NO];
}
```

In `mouseUp:`, destroy the timer:

```
- (void)mouseUp: (NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [mouseTimer invalidate];
    mouseTimer = nil;
}
```

If the timer fires, then you know that the mouse button has been held down for your specified period of time, and you can take whatever action you like:

```
- (void)mouseWasHeld: (NSTimer *)tim {
    NSEvent * mouseDownEvent = [tim userInfo];
    mouseTimer = nil;
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Your `mouseUp` handler should also take care of whatever needs to happen if the user clicked on something but did not keep holding the button down. Also, is there a guarantee that the timer will not fire after `mouseUp:` is entered but before `[mouseTimer invalidate];` is called?

Comment: @Mike: 1) Of course; I leave that as an exercise to the OP. 2) The timer and event handling are both queued inputs to the run loop, so that shouldn't be an issue. I can't think of a way to make that guarantee otherwise.

Comment: Im getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS once I held the mouse down for the period of time and called the mouseWasHeld.  It happens as soon as I release the mouse but only if mouseWasHeld is called.  Do you know what I did wrong?

Comment: You need to set mouseTimer to nil in mouseWasHeld: Otherwise, the timer fires and is invalidated, and then you send invalidate to it again in mouseUp:

Answer (score 11):

Starting with OS X 10.6, you can use `NSEvent`’s `pressedMouseButtons` method from anywhere:

```
NSUInteger mouseButtonMask = [NSEvent pressedMouseButtons];
BOOL leftMouseButtonDown = (mouseButtonMask & (1 << 0)) != 0;
BOOL rightMouseButtonDown = (mouseButtonMask & (1 << 1)) != 0;
```

The method returns indices of the mouse buttons currently down as a mask. `1 << 0` corresponds to the left mouse button, `1 << 1` to right mouse button, and `1 << n`, n >= 2 to other mouse buttons.

With this it’s not necessary to catch the `mouseDown:`, `mouseDragged:`, or `mouseUp:` events.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember the mouseDown is only fired when the user first clicks the element, not when held down.

The solution to your problem is to define a BOOL in your .h like so:

```
bool mouseIsHeldDown = false;
```

Then in your mouseDown:

```
mouseIsHeldDown = true;
```

And in your mouseUP:

```
mouseIsHeldDown = false;
```

You can then check if mouseIsHeldDown = true anywhere in your code.

Hope this fixes your problem!