# Objective-C Why do some mouse events fire and others don´t

Tags: objective-c, macos, mouseevent

my View controller works fine so far except one thing:
I have a couple of MouseEvents and some fire and others don´t.

```
- (void)mouseWasHeld: (NSTimer *)tim {
    **// this works not**
}

- (void) mouseMoved:(NSEvent*)someEvent {
    **// this works not**
}

-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    // this works
}

-(void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event {
    // this works
}

-(void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)event {
// this works
}
```

I don´t see why two events don´t fire any clues?

Thanks a lot
Ronald

Comment: Those marked with this:     **// this works not**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mouseMoved:` will not be called unless you add the Tracking area.

```
 NSTrackingAreaOptions options = NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways;
 NSTrackingArea *trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:self.frame options:options owner:self userInfo:nil];
 [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `mouseWasHeld:` seems to be a callback of a timer setup anywhere else. Look for `@selector(mouseWasHeld:)` in your code and find out why the timer is not scheduled.
2. `mouseMoved:` is only dispatched if the window [is told to do so](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/EventOverview/MouseTrackingEvents/MouseTrackingEvents.html) using `-[NSWindow setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:]`.

Comment: In particular, `mouseWasHeld:` requires code like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967118/detect-mouse-being-held-down